# How to plot the mean silhouette score for each cluster in matplotlib python

Tags: matplotlib, silhouette

I have 78 rows and 131 columns and I need to plot the mean silhouette score for each cluster in python matplotlib as a line graph. I did these codes and worked great but I don't know how to plot?

```
mean = KMeans(n_clusters = 2)
kmean.fit(Data1)
centroids = kmean.cluster_centers_
print("Shape of Centroids Array: " + str(centroids.shape))

print()
print(centroids)

from collections import Counter
labels = kmean.labels_
c = Counter(labels)
print(c.most_common())

Record_array =Data1.values
print(Record_array)
mean_sihouette_score = ss(Record_array, labels)
print(mean_sihouette_score)

for cluster_number in range(0,2):

    print("Cluster {} contains {} samples with percentage of {:.2f}%".format(cluster_number, c[cluster_number], c[cluster_number]/sum(c.values()) *100))
```

Comment: [plot silhouette analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html)  The example has code for plotting that may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Coding to plot average silhouette score is not an easy job.
I usually have yellowbrick it done.

Here, you could take a look.

https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/silhouette.html

or their code right here (please install yellowbrick beforehand)

```
from yellowbrick.cluster import SilhouetteVisualizer

model = KMeans(5, random_state=42)
visualizer = SilhouetteVisualizer(model, colors='yellowbrick')

visualizer.fit(X)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()        # Finalize and render the figure
```

Comment: You wrote `visualizer.fit(X)` but there is no `X`.